# How do you load multiple chrome extensions when running nightwatch tests?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, nightwatch

**I've figured out how to run one chrome extension by using the following**:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["test"],
  "webdriver" : {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": "node_modules/.bin/chromedriver",
    "cli_args": ["--verbose"],
    "port": 9515
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions" : {
          "args": [
            "--load-extension=/pathToFirstExtension",
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**However, running two extensions is not working**. 
**I've tried the following**:

```
  "args": [
            "--load-extension=/pathToFirstExtension, /pathToSecondExtension",
          ]
```

**And this**:

```
"args": [
            "--load-extension=/pathToFirstExtension", 
            "--load-extension=/pathToSecondExtension",
        ]
```

**And this**:

```
"args": [
            "--load-extension=/pathToFirstExtension /pathToSecondExtension",
        ]
```

**And also base64 encoded strings comma separated in a list like this**:

```
chromeOptions: {
          extensions: [
            keywords.base64,
            avgPrice.base64
          ]
        }
```

**I'm using module.exports in individual js files where the base64 encoded strings are in objects with a key of base64**

**How do you load more than one chrome extension for nightwatch tests**?

Answer (score 1):

**The cuplrit was the space between the comma separated strings**!

**In case anyone finds this useful - this is now working for me**:

```
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

module.exports = {
  src_folders : ["test"],
  test_settings: {
    default: {
      webdriver: {
        start_process: true,
        server_path: chromedriver.path,
        port: 4444,
        cli_args: ['--port=4444']
      },
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        chromeOptions: {
          args: [
            "--load-extension=/pathToExtensionOne,/pathToExtensionTwo",
            "window-position=2560,0",
            "window-size=400,300"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    chrome: {
      webdriver: {
        server_path: chromedriver.path
      },
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        chromeOptions: {
          args: []
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I'm also able to set the window size / position.

FWIW, I'm using a nightwatch.conf.js instead of nightwatch.json

**In my package.json**:

```
  "scripts": {
    "nightwatch": "nightwatch -c ./nightwatch.conf.js"
  }
```

**To run this, execute the following in the terminal**:

```
npm run nightwatch
```